# Create a drop down check box list in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9

I need to create a drop down check box list like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/evfnLn0x/). The problem with the code over there is that it is not working in IE9. I'm getting an error saying getElementsByClassName is not a property in the below code:

```
var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');
var items = document.getElementById('items');
        checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt) {
            if (items.classList.contains('visible')){
                items.classList.remove('visible');
                items.style.display = "none";
            }

            else{
                items.classList.add('visible');
                items.style.display = "block";
            }


        }

        items.onblur = function(evt) {
            items.classList.remove('visible');
        }
```

Can someone please help me out on how to create a drop down check box list? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **classList** property is not available for an IE browser below 10. If you wanna do this you're gonna have to use **className** instead and check for the index of that class. For example:

```
if (items.className.indexOf('visible') > -1){
            items.className -= 'visible';
            items.style.display = "none";
        }
```

If your item has the **visible** class it will return its index and if it doesn't have that class it will return -1. [I have created a fiddle from yours here to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/uot6nvne/1/)